# Spark SQL and timezones - How to transform a unix timestamp to a localised timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timezone

From a Spark DataFrame I need to convert a epoch/unix timestamp column (eg. 1509102527 = GMT: Friday, 27 October 2017 11:08:47) to a localised timestamp in order to get the local hour in a specific timezone.

Is there a Spark SQL function that can take the unix timestamp and return a localised java.sql.Timestamp?

I already tried to use `from_unixtime` function, but it returns a localised timestamp based on the default system timezone of the machine the code is running on. The only solution I found so far is to convert that timestamp back to UTC and then from UTC to the target Timezone. 
This is a unit test that works with the workaround, but there should be a better way to do it.

```
test("timezone localization should not change effective unix timestamp") {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val df = Seq(1509102527)
    .toDF("unix_timestamp")
    .withColumn("machine_localised_timestamp", from_unixtime('unix_timestamp))
    .withColumn("utc_timestamp", to_utc_timestamp('machine_localised_timestamp, TimeZone.getDefault().getID()))
    .withColumn("local_time", from_utc_timestamp('utc_timestamp, "Europe/Amsterdam"))
    .withColumn("local_hour", hour('local_time))
    .withColumn("reverted_unix_timestamp", unix_timestamp('local_time))

  df.show(false)

  val row = df.collect()(0)
  row(row.fieldIndex("unix_timestamp")) shouldBe 1509102527
  row(row.fieldIndex("reverted_unix_timestamp")) shouldBe 1509102527
  row(row.fieldIndex("local_hour")) shouldBe 13
}
```

Comment: This question is relevant to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17971) Spark issue, marked as "Not A Problem".  I would expect from_unixtime function to accept a timezone as second parameter, instead of defaulting to the machine local timezone.

Comment: As mentioned in the JIRA you provided, I don't think Spark API will support timezone specification in the udf `from_unixtime`? I had a similar need recently where I needed to specify a timezone as opposed to the machine local - and ended up doing it manually. But happy to hear about a more streamlined solution.