# Convert string into timestamp in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, date-format

```
val format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
df.show()
```

> c_time
>   2017-09-15T16:43:40.5370791Z000000000000000

```
df.withColumn("c_time", unix_timestamp(df("c_time"), format).cast("timestamp"))
```

df.show()

> c_time
>   2017-09-15 05:43:10

I think it is converting in other timezone.

I need the format like 2017-09-15 16:43:40.5370791

Comment: Did you have a look at [Spark SQL and timezones - How to transform a unix timestamp to a localised timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973884/spark-sql-and-timezones-how-to-transform-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-localised-times#comment80896509_46973884)?

Comment: The `Z` in `2017-09-15T16:43:40.5370791Z` refers to Zulu time zone, better known as UTC or offset 0. Could `05:43:10` be in your computer’s local time zone? I think it would correspond to a zone offset of -11. Somewhere in the Pacific?